# facebook login popup opens in a new tab in one of internet explorer 9

Tags: facebook, authentication

Hi i'm using the JS SDK with this code to log in using facebook:

```
<div class="fb-login-button inlineBlock" data-scope="email" on-login="onLoginWithFacebook();">Connect using Facebook</div>
```

This works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, it works also fine in IE9 of one PC, but not on the other PC.
IE9 version on the other PC is 9.0.8112.16421, update version: 9.0.4

In this IE, it opens the facebook login window in a new tab instead of a popup, and after you succesfully login to facebook the window redirects to a blank page with url : https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php?...

On the other PC, where IE9 is working fine, the login window opens in a popup and after login the popup closes and the main window refresh ok.

I've reset IE options to default on the faulting PC without success.

Any idea where to search for logs ? There seems to be none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem : IE Chrome Frame.

When IE renders my web site using google's "IE Chrome Frame", for an unknown reason the facebook login popup opens in a new tab instead of a popup. The new tab is rendered using IE not IE chrome frame, thus breaking javascript connections between the popup and its parent window.

I may be a bug in IE Chrome Frame, or in the way facebook opens the login popup, i'm still searching.

The IE Chrome Frame compatibility is important for IE6 users.

See http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started/differences-between-chrome-and-chrome-frame

And a "solution" (complicated solution): http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-frame/browse_thread/thread/388e872d5ce4efa2?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

IE can be [set to open popups in a new tab](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/force-ie-to-open-link-in-new-tab/).  I suspect that's your problem.